# xlsxwriter - grouping via set_row()

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, xlsxwriter

I tried to set some groups in xlsxwriter but it seems I can't get the <kbd>+</kbd> Symbol at the top of my group. As it is setting the grouping row-wise I tried to write a function that takes the workbook, the worksheet index and a start/end as well as the level. But whatever I do the grouping symbol in excel never appears in the first row. Funny thing is, if I use something like start_row + 5 for the collapsing row I will get a second <kbd>+</kbd> at the right row, but still another one at the end. Does anyone know if its possible?

The [examples](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_outline2.html) show grouping just for the last row of a group.

```
def set_group(out_wb, ws_index, start_row, end_row, level):
  #added as i used an offset
  start_row = start_row
  end_row = end_row

  out_wb.worksheets()[ws_index].set_row(start_row, None, None, {'level': level, 'collapsed': True})
  for i in range(start_row + 1, end_row):
    out_wb.worksheets()[ws_index].set_row(i, None, None, {'level': level, 'hidden': True})


return out_wb
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [`outline_settings()`](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/worksheet.html#outline_settings) worksheet method and set `symbols_below` to `False`:

```
worksheet.outline_settings(symbols_below=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm with `xlsxwriter` in version `0.5.5` and the command line is

```
worksheet.outline_settings(outline_below=False)
```